# Java: Point of subdirectories

Tags: java

First of all: I'm not entirely familiar with Java, and the few things I know I have learned while playing with Java.

However, there is something I have noticed in pretty much any Opensource Java project - the use of alot of subdirectories for the sources, which usually look like so:

```
./src/main/java/com/somedomainname/projectname/sourcefile.java
```

Now, why so many subdirectories? what's the deal with the domainname?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The domain name is used for the package name - so that file would be for the class

```
com.somedomainname.projectname.sourcefile
```

where `com.somedomainname.projectname` is the package.

Conventionally, source file organization mirrors the package layout. The normal Java compiler doesn't actually enforce directory structure (although some IDEs such as Eclipse will complain if you put things in the "wrong" directories) but it *does* force public classes to be in a file with the same name. Non-public classes can go in any file, but conventionally the filename matches the class name there, too. It makes it very easy to navigate to any class without any prior knowledge.

The Java language specification doesn't say that a compiler *must* enforce the convention for public classes; it explicitly says that it *can* though. See [section 7.2 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.2) for more details.

Comment: By convention, the `SourceFile` should be bumpy case.

Comment: @Erick: By convention, it's called upper camel case. =P

Comment: @Colin: By convention, it's called **CENSORED**

Comment: I had always heard that called StudlyCaps - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StudlyCaps

Answer (score 3):

This directory structure is used as a convention that shows where the library is from and separates it from other sources.

One reason to use this structure is that is the standard used by [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

Maven is a build tool that helps to manage the dependencies of a project.  Maven is designed for convention over configuration, so you will often see this directory structure to make it work with Maven.

Maven specifies that the directory structure start with /src/main/java for Java files, and the rest is based on the naming convention for namespaces.

The use of the domain name in the path is to prevent class collisions.  If 2 different libraries both supply a class with the same name, the domain name namespace allows them to both be used.

Comment: -1 you don't need to use maven, this information can be misleading

Comment: Using the domain name I have seen used outside of Maven, but I was under the impression that the src/main/java/ prefix is Maven specific.  Is this not the case?  Most of my recent Java experience is with Maven.

Comment: If it is the case that it is Maven specific, it does not mean that only Maven packages can look that way.  I have seen projects that use Ant + Ivy with the same setup.  I think it is more of a de facto standard these days.

Comment: Agree that mentioning Maven is misleading.  Just because a directory structure looks that way doesn't mean a project is using Maven - or that by using that structure a project has to be Maven.  That directory structure just happens to be the convention that Maven follows.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I updated the answer to reflect that Maven is just one reason to use this structure but not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

> A Java package is a mechanism for
>   organizing Java classes into
>   namespaces similar to the modules of
>   Modula. Java packages can be stored in
>   compressed files called JAR files,
>   allowing classes to download faster as
>   a group rather than one at a time.
>   Programmers also typically use
>   packages to organize classes belonging
>   to the same category or providing
>   similar functionality.

...from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package

Answer (score 1):

subdirectories as an organizational tool so that you don't just have one directory with tons of java files.  The reason you often see a domain name is that conventionally people derive java package names from their domain names in order to prevent collisions with other developers.  So although we both might have a util.Stringutil class, if I name mine com.mydomain.util.Stringutil and yours is com.yourdomain.util.Stringutil, we can have a project containing both classes without a collision.

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting read on java packages and directories in the newer O'Reilly book [Java: The Good Parts](http://books.google.ca/books?id=YMQqZoc6L3EC&pg=PA39&dq=java+the+good+parts+chapter+4&hl=en&ei=WGK3TLbBGc3CnAev-KSoBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=java%20the%20good%20parts%20chapter%204&f=false)  (starting at the bottom of page 46).

> ...the required interaction between the package system and the filesystem 
>   is both  regrettable and a pain...

Comment: Thanks for the link--I read the section in the book. It apparently has to do with Sun originally hoping to store the java files in a db--the directories were a stand-in for the db structure they were hoping to impose. Being a C/C++ programmer and emacs user, I can vouch for my unequivocal detest of this system. It is pointless, and furthermore very confusing. I am happy I am not the only person who suffers this indignity. I think most Java (only) folks don't see this because they typically use Eclipse. Before I sign off, I know there will be some Java/C people who will want to say "not me"...

Answer (score 0):

This is meant as a standard to define unique locations for java source code.  It is convention to follow this package structure, which is why you see it everywhere.  It's not required to do it that way - you can name your packages whatever you want.  It is very commonplace to follow this convention, however.

```
package prefix.organization.project.ClassName;
package prefix.organization.project.package.ClassName;
package prefix.organization.project.package.subpackage.ClassName;
```

When storing Java source code files, each part of the package name translates into a subdirectory.  So the same three classes shown above would be located in the corresponding directories off the main classpath.

```
prefix/organization/project/ClassName.java
prefix/organization/project/package/ClassName.java
prefix/organization/project/package/subpackage/ClassName.java
```

When compiling by hand, be sure that the main classpath directory is the current directory or is within the classpath in order that the source code files can be found.

As for the `src/main/java` part of it, it seems this comes from Maven.  I've never used that software.  I don't understand why they would need so many, since my projects (I use Eclipse) just have a `src` folder there instead.

Answer (score 0):

`./src/main/java/com/somedomainname/projectname/sourcefile.java` : Decomposed

1. src/main/java
   this is the directory that needs to be passed to the javac compiler stating where the source code for compilation can be found.
   1.1 src/test/java
   this is where the unit test classes should be kept.
   1.2 src/main/resources and src/test/resources
   these are the corresponding directories where resources such as properties files should be kept.
   1.3 Separate output directories.
   *main* and *test * classes and resources should be *compiled* to their own separate output directories. Maven uses *target/classes* and *target/test-classes*. When you jar your compiled class files for distribution, you don't want to include test classes and test resource files.
2. com/somedomainname/projectname
   this directory structure corresponds to the package declaration in the classes found in projectname i.e. `package com.somedomainname.projectname`
3. SourceFile.java corresponds to the class name that it defines, and it should by convention start with an uppercase character see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html
4. Also in the link above you will find out that the default package naming convention uses the domain name in reverse.

Answer (score -1):

The [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html) defines a [package naming convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions) that says that package names should include a domain name, as it provides a globally-rooted namespace.

The source files need to be in subfolders that match the package name, because the Sun Java compiler, `javac`, <strike>enforces</strike> strongly encourages it.  Additionally, many other build tools and IDEs also either strongly encourage or require that the source .java files are stored in paths that match the package.

Comment: javac doesn't enforce the package structure.

Comment: @Jon: It seems you're right. I posted my answer, and then went looking for citations and I couldn't find one.  It seems javac merely strongly encourages the package structure, although from experience it's well-nigh impossible to circumvent it if you have other Java tools in the mix.  I'll edit to correct.